# Using OAuth Python service with Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth

Google App Engine provides an experimental, bleeding-edge OAuth service in its Python SDK, but fails to provide simple example to work with. Has anyone succeeded in working with it? If so, could you provide a snippet?

Comment: What, you mean apart from the [detailed documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/oauth/overview.html)?

Comment: Yes, apart from it. This documentation does not state, for instance, how the "client secret" is passed to the service provider. Or is it managed internally? I was really confused after reading it, I felt like a lot was missing.

Comment: You work with it as you would any other provider.  It has a few quirks, but the basics work.

Comment: @RobertKluin: "but the basics work", but the question was: how do I use the basic functions.  Your response is rather unhelpful.

Comment: @AdamParkin, you literally work with it as you would with any other oauth provider.  This is all clearly documented in the docs (see Daniel's comment).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here](http://ikaisays.com/2011/05/26/setting-up-an-oauth-provider-on-google-app-engine/) is a very good tutorial